# image is not loading/showing after routing react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have been working with `react-router-dom` for quite a time but not faced this problem at all, everything working fine with the navbar image when I'm in the `"/"` root address but when I route to `/student/view/:id` the navbar image is not loading!

Here's the code!!

Main file code:

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={StudentCard} />
      <Route exact path="/student/view/:id" component={StudentView} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Navbar file code:

```
 <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white">
  <div className="container">
    <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
      <img src="assets/images/administrator.png" height="50px" alt="admin" />
    </Link>
```

Comment: Is `assets` a folder in your public directory

Comment: yes it is in public folder

Comment: Try `/assets/images/administrator.png`, plus remember to check the network tab for more info about the error ( or weird behaviour  )

Comment: thank you very much now i know whats the problem because of you it was that "/" that causing problem, thanks for increasing my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is as simple as add `/` at the beginning of the link to the image:

Just change `<img src="assets/images/administrator.png"`

to `<img src="/assets/images/administrator.png"`

*Original answer were posted in comments by @GayatriDipali, I've moved it to answer section just to make it more readable!*